# How to use Swift's JSONSerialization when JSON returns a single string

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

So this is likely a very basic question, but I was curious how you would handle parsing a JSON object that returns as a single string using JSONSerialization in Swift. So I'm playing around with a free Harry Potter API and noticed that one of the routes returns a single string (https://www.potterapi.com/v1/sortinghat) and the response it gives is simply a single string of one of the four houses in Harry Potter.

`"Ravenclaw"`

Below was my attempt.

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? String
    print("json: \(json)")
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I thought simply typecasting as a `String` would suffice but I just get the following error: "*Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.*"

I know there are better ways to parse JSON such as using Codable but I am just trying to understand how this would work before moving on to tackling that.

Comment: It’s not JSON so you can’t parse it. Capture the data and encode it to UTF.

Comment: @DanielStorm That would include the quotation marks and the newline, which are almost certainly not part of the value. This is a JSON string. It's needs to be parsed to get the intended value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSONSerialization is the wrong tool for this. You want to use JSONDecoder, which is much more useful in Swift:

```
let json = Data("""
"Ravenclaw"
""".utf8)

let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: json)
```

Note that this requires iOS 13.1 or macOS 10.15.1. Otherwise you will need to use @vadian's answer.

Comment: one question about the above because the request returns a random house I can't hardcode the response so how would I handle that?

Comment: My `json` variable here is just to demonstrate it for a playground. You just need to pass your `data` variable. This isn't hardcoded.

Comment: oh okay yeah thanks so much, just trying to figure out all of this so sorry if the question was an obvious one

Comment: `JSONDecoder` uses JSONSerialization with default (no) options. This code throws a `dataCorrupted` error, `debugDescription`: *"The given data was not valid JSON."* and underlying error description *"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."*

Comment: @vadian I tested this in an 11.2.1 playground, and it doesn't have trouble. I'm familiar with the code you're describing, but it does seem to work fine.

Comment: @RobNapier Strange, in my 11.2.1 Playground it fails and this is actually the previous behavior.

Comment: P.S. I just read the source code. `JSONSerialization` is indeed called with no options.

Comment: nix.codes: Can you confirm whether this answer works for you? I'm having trouble reproducing @vadian's issue. Here's how I'm using it, with screenshot of the result. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/585ab20c5f01bbf81b6fce4ecf119266

Comment: @RobNapier I figured out what's going on. *JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder now support top-level "primitive" types (strings, numbers, booleans) by default.* It's not implemented in JSONDecoder but apparently in `JSONSerialization` on  iOS (13.1) and macOS (10.15.1). See the comments on https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6163. I'm still on Mojave.

Comment: @vadian Thank you; that's an important note for the answer. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

To deserialize a non-collection type you have to set the `.allowFragments` option

```
let jsonString = """
"Slytherin"
"""

do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(jsonString.utf8), options: .allowFragments) as? String {
        print("json: ", json)
    }
} catch {
    print("Error: ", error)
}
```

`JSONDecoder` does not work, it calls underlying `JSONSerialization` with ***no*** options.

The sense of deserializing a string to a string is another question, this does the same

```
if let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("json: \(json)")
}
```

**Edit:** `JSONDecoder` **does** work on iOS 13.1+ and macOS 10.15.1+