# Time and date formatter SwiftUI JSON data

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

Hopefully this an easy one. Im trying to display the date and time in a list In an iOS application using SwiftUI. I'm having issues with the code at the moment and getting this error message: `Cannot convert value of type 'PostListViewModel' to expected argument type 'Data'`

Please find the code below:

```
struct PostViewModel {
    var post: Post
    init(post: Post) {
        self.post = post
    }
    var startTime: Date {       
        let data = PostListViewModel()
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.DateFormat)
        let postDate = try! decoder.decode(startTime.self, from: data)
        return self.post.startTime
    }    
}
```

---

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let DateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Can you see any issues with the code?

Comment: The `data` variable is being initialized as `PostListViewModel()` and being passed to an argument that expects a `Data` type.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Please elaborate what you are going to accomplish. You can decode only a **Type** from **Data** representing a  JSON **string**.

Comment: Also, the `startTime` computed property is calculating `postDate` but is returning `self.post.startTime`

Comment: Sorry, what im trying to do is convert the start time into a different format, im not quite sure how to do this exactly. the Json data is in the format 2019-11-08 20:00:00 but I want it to show Nov 08 and get the time separately. Is this possible with the current code?

Comment: No, it's not possible with this code. `JSONDecoder` can only decode collection objects (array or dictionary) and the result `postDate` is unused anyway. Just use one date formatter with two different date format strings or two date formatters.

Comment: @vadian IMO, JSON is a red herring here (and unnecessary), but JSONDecoder can decode non-collection types. It's just JSONSerialization that has this restriction. We were just discussing this confusion over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236554/how-to-use-swifts-jsonserialization-when-json-returns-a-single-string/59236933#59236933

Comment: But to the OP, it's not clear here what `PostListViewModel` is or where you expect `startTime` to come from, or what you want the result to be. It doesn't seem that JSON is involved in the code you've posted. It looks like you just want to take a date string and convert it into a different date string. That's just two DateFormatters (one to parse the string into a date, and another to convert the date into a string). There are no "dates" in JSON.

Comment: @RobNapier I disagree. `JSONDecoder` calls `JSONSerialization` with no options. Your sample code in the linked answer causes a *JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set* error

Comment: So all of the data is pulled from a URL using Json. I am able to retrieve all of the data fine, but I want to change the date format from 2019-11-08 20:00:00 to Nov 08. I've been trying many different ways but cannot figure it out. Im quite new to this so its most likely just me being dumb. How would I use a date decoder on the Json string and where would I need to put this in my project as I have 2 classes that define the startTime as a string which the code for these are struct 

    Post : Codable {
    

    let startTime: String

Comment: and

struct PostViewModel {
    
    var post: Post
    
    init(post: Post) {
        self.post = post 
} 
var startTime: String {
return self.post.startTime
    }

I then use observed binding and put this data into a list. However when I try display the date it show it as  2019-11-08 20:00:00 which is not what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert a date string to a `Date` and then to another date string use one date formatter with two different date format strings

```
struct PostViewModel {
    var post: Post

    init(post: Post) {
        self.post = post
    }

    var startTime: String {       
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        if let date = formatter.date(from: post.startTime) {      
           formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"
           return formatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
           return post.startTime
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Dude you are the greatest. That exactly what I wanted! Been trying to do this for days now. Thank you so much

Comment: Would it be possible to also extract the Time in a separate string?

Comment: You could return a tuple and apply a third date format to get the time. Or convert the initial string to `DateComponents`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I've just tried researching the dateComponents but when I implement it in my code it causes errors, I'm sure i'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what. Do I just need to modify the code above so that it has, let string = dateComponents[0] and let string = dateComponents[1] and copy the format for the date and change it to time instead?

Comment: No, you have to call `Calendar.current.dateComponents(: [.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)` and compose the strings from the single components. Changing the date format to `HH:mm`, then getting the time and return a tuple might be easier.